# Create session using retrieved data

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin

I have a login page where user insert their username and password.
I create a session which will display the username of the user at the main page using below code.

However, instead of the username, I want to display the user's full name. How do I display the full name using `$_SESSION['username']`?

My table name is `users` and consist of column `fullname`, `username` and `password`.

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
      array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use db query like `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to get data from db

```
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results );

        $_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['fullname'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: index.php');
    }else {
      array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
}
```

for more : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_row.asp